# How to make class or module just for import/export job ( classes )

Tags: typescript

Explanation (in some class i want to import more classes) 
 Look like this :

```
 import myClass1 'pathto1';
 import myClass2 'pathto2';
 import myClassn 'pathton';
```

I want simple to make bypass with one file ( class export ) :
 To be like this (in one line):

```
 import AllMyClasses 'pathToLib';
```

What is the best look for that file ?

Comment: you can just re-export them in your lib file like this `export {myClass1} from 'pathto1'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you write your "bypass" file like this:

```
import { MyClass1 } from './path/to/one';
import { MyClass2 } from './path/to/otwo';
import { MyClass3 } from './path/to/three';

export { MyClass1, MyClass2, MyClass2 };
```

You can then import all of these classes in another file like this:

```
import * as AllMyClasses from '/path/to/bypass/file';

const m = new AllMyClasses.MyClass1();
```

Comment: Is it correct : import MyClass3 from './path/to/three'; if i use "one file one class" system.